# Unable to fit the large text in table row in TableLayout

Tags: java, android

In the TableLayout under the Table row i have created two TextViews, But when i am running the app my text is not getting fitted into the table coloumn, instead it's getting exceeded and some part of the text is not visible.

My Android code are as follows:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top_layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shadow_layout"
    android:padding="6dip"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">

      <TableLayout
       android:id="@+id/orgSummary_table"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"

       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@+id/orgSummary_image"
       android:layout_alignStart="@+id/orgSummary_image">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/orgSummary_tb_founded"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/orgSummary_tr1_founded"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle_text"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Founded"
            android:textColor="#d4fff700"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/orgSummary_tr2_founded"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle_text"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="#d4fff700"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"/>

    </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

From my activity i am calling the code and setting the text in second coloumn
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.orgSummary_tr2_founded)).setText("some long text");

But only some part of the text is visible

Answer (score 0):

try

```
<TableRow
        android:id="@+id/orgSummary_tb_founded"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp">
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/orgSummary_tr1_founded"
            android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle_text"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:text="Founded"
            android:textColor="#d4fff700"
            android:paddingLeft="30dp"/>
</ScrollView>


    </TableRow>
```

use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` for TableRow

Comment: I tried the options but not getting, the text is still missing

Comment: is your text more than screen?

Comment: Yes i think. because some of the text are not visible

Comment: then you should use scrollview

Comment: place any textview inside of a scrollview

Comment: Mine text is getting out from the right side of the screen... in every line i am missing some 2-3 words.. does this will solve by scrollview

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59403/discussion-between-anand-and-zohreh).

Comment: I am still not getting the result